# how to store-result of dynamic subquery inside main query to use that value further

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a long query that has some sub-queries. I want to store the sub-query results to variable as I also want to use them in next sub-query so that I don't give the server that load.

I am giving an example here and hope that it describes my situation. Just focus on the part between `// question starts from here` and `//question ends here`. The other part is working fine, but I am desperate to use full `SELECT` sub-query in place of those terms I used as alias or I want them be as variable.

```
SELECT a.field1, a.field2, b.field1, b.field2, c.field1,
(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM project_expense WHERE job_id=c.job_id
    GROUP BY c.invoice HAVING invoice<>'') AS p_expense,
(SELECT charges FROM ship_details WHERE some_condition=match) AS ship_exp,
(SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(---some time params---)/3600) FROM production_log
    WHERE job_id=c.job_id) AS p_hours,
(SELECT SUM(revenue) FROM exp_list WHERE job_id=c.job_id) AS p_revenue,

**
//question starts from here

(p_revenue/(p_expense*p_hours)+ship_exp) AS p_margin

//question ends here
**

FROM table_1 a
LEFT JOIN table_2 b
INNER JOIN table_3 c
WHERE c.date BETWEEN '2016-09-01' AND '2016-09-15'
ORDER BY b.company_name ASC
```

Is it possible to store result of each sub-query to a variable?
So I can lessen the load of query, and also that is proper way for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Having uncorrelated subqueries is not such a terrible thing, as the query optimizer should ideally only have to compute then once only for the entire query.

Comment: Yes @TimBiegeleisen I agree with it, but still I want to make it possible because I am having some miss-match in data as output so if I am going to correct Its very time consuming and headache. As the query here is just for sample this is just part of another sub-system. So..